# How can I use alerts like the volume alert in the iPhone in my apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, message, alert

What is the kind of alerts like the iPhone volume

See picture:
http://caius.name/images/ringer.jpg

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in support for those alerts, but they're pretty simple to create on your own. You can construct the alert programatically, or what I've done in the past is just to create an image like the one you linked to and add any dynamic components as subviews.

If you want something significantly more powerful, check out MBProgressHUD.

http://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD